# Function is trivial endomorphism

Tags: representation-theory

I am reading a textbook on representation theory which says the following.

$G$ is a finite group with irreducible representation $\rho:G\to GL(V)$ over field $k$ (possibly algebraically closed, there's an assumption that all fields are algebraically closed which I'm not certain extends to this page in the book). $\phi$ is a class function from $G$ to $k$ satisfying $(\phi,\chi_\rho)=0$. Define
$$T=\frac{1}{\#G}\sum\limits_{g\in G}\phi(g^{-1})\rho_g.$$
The text claims that $T=0$. I am not sure how to see this. I see why $T\in End_GV$, so if $k$ is algebraically closed then we can identify it with some element of $k$ (and regardless $End_GV$ is a division ring, by Schur's lemma), but I don't see why $T$ must be $0$.

Is there something that I'm missing here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I presume you are in characteristic zero.

As you say, $T$ is a scalar matrix (Schur's lemma).

The trace of $T$ is
$$\frac1{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}\phi(g^{-1})\textrm{Tr}(\rho_g)=\frac1{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}\phi(g^{-1})\chi_\rho(g)=(\phi,\chi_\rho)=0.$$
As $T=\lambda I$ and has trace zero, then $\lambda=0$.

Comment: Nice, thanks! Does this work even if $k$ is not algebraically closed?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $T=aI$ is a scalar multiple of the identity map.

Taking traces yields $\mathrm{tr}(T)=(\dim V)a=(\phi,\chi)=0$, so $a=0$.

(I assume $\dim V$ is invertible in the base field.)

Comment: Nice, thanks! I think $\dim V$ need not be invertible in $k$, as $tr \ T=(\phi,\chi_\rho)=0$ independently of the structure of $End_GV$. Do you know if it's still true if $End_GV$ is not isomorphic to $k$?

Comment: Good question. Not sure if $\dim V=0$ makes it possible for $T\ne 0$. As for your comment on Angina's answer - since the only fact we used when proving $T=0$ is that $\dim V$ is invertible, it doesn't really matter if $k$ is algebraically closed. Do you understand the proof we're presenting?

Comment: I think I follow, but it seems that the conclusion $tr T=0$ immediately implies $T=0$ when $T$ is a scalar, which is not necessarily the case when $k$ is not algebraically closed. Is that right?

Comment: Ah, I see. Algebraic closure is relevant in the application of Schur's lemma, yes.